# ffmpeg конвертирование многих аудио файлов

Tags: bat, ffmpeg

у меня есть много mp3 файлов с битрейтом 320 в одной папке. как с помощью ffmpeg.exe сконвертировать все bat файлом например до 96 кбит/сек с такими же названиями и сохранить в другую папку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот самый простой вариант. Проходим по файлам в текущем каталоге и пишем результат в папку out, если ее нет создаем.

```
@echo OFF

IF exist out ( echo out exists ) ELSE ( mkdir out && echo out created)

for %%i in (*.mp3) do (
 echo %%i
 ffmpeg -i "%%i" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k out/"%%i"
 )
```